# Explaining instances of a machine learning regressor

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I trained an XGBoost regressor, and I'm looking for a way to interpret new instances that the model will receive in production.
There's a nice solution for classification models ([Lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime)), but it doesn't offer explanations to regression problems.

Does anyone know of an existing "explainer" for regressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lime introduced support for regression problems in their latest version. A notebook with examples is available [here](https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Using%2Blime%2Bfor%2Bregression.html).